# How to return generic abstract class?

Tags: c#

I have something like this:

```
abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    protected BaseClass(){}
}

class Class1 : BaseClass<Class1>
{
    public static Class1 Instance = new Class1();
    private Class1(){}          
}

class Class2 : BaseClass<Class2>
{
    public static Class2 Instance = new Class2();
    private Class2(){}      
}

...
public BaseClass<T> Method<T>(int z) where T: BaseClass<T>
{
    switch(z)
    {
        case 1: 
            return Class1.Instance;
        case 2:
            return Class2.Instance;
    }
}
```

That is very important that those classes cannot be instantiated since their construstors are private so we cannot do like

`public BaseClass<T> Method<T>(int z) where T: BaseClass<T>,` **new()**

How can I use abstract class as return type ?? I just can not work this out. Would appreciate for any assisstance here.

Comment: The thing is indeed that "Method" is like factory method... whole dependency is a bit complicate and I posted just as simple skeleton as possible. The problem arises that I cannot in switch clause return those Class1.Instance because it says "cannot convert Class1 to return type BaseClass<T>

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you can't really have the method be generic. For instance, what would happen if I called:

```
BaseClass<Class1> foo = Method<Class1>(2);
```

You need a single point of truth - either the type argument, or the normal argument. You can make it the method argument by having a non-generic base class (either by making the existing base class non-generic, or introducing a non-generic base class to that). Change the return type of `Method` to this non-generic base class.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    public abstract T Instance { get; }

    protected BaseClass(){}
}
```

maybe? You can't inherit static stuff I believe...

---

On a closer look... I don't think what you are trying to do is even possible... what are you trying to do anyways?

---

A type constraint is a type constraint. You are trying to change the type constraint in the method kind of. which obviously doesn't work, and shouldn't work. I think you need to think of a different way of attacking your problem. Whatever it is...

Comment: That won't help. How does one call the Instance property without having already created an instance of the object?

Comment: well, good point :p but you can't inherit static stuff. But in this case, why does he need to do it through those static properties in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Pattern). Your factory can have a method on it to get the instance. The first time it's called, it creates the instance. On subsequent calls, it can return the already-created instance.